# Urban positional accuracy of Google Streetview

Tags: gps, geolocation, google, position, google-street-view

How does Google Streetview have accurate locations in urban environments, such as [in tunnels](https://www.google.nl/maps/@39.6790999,-105.9063194,3a,75y,269.14h,79.15t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sOioEB9g0APArYIP4GhoBXw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656), [below buildings](https://www.google.nl/maps/@52.3209821,4.9697503,3a,75y,150.39h,66.88t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s3I9o4MsBcp4gvU3vHsO-aA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=nl) and [next to buildings](https://www.google.nl/maps/@40.7578734,-73.9852753,3a,75y,304.14h,96.92t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sY0UP3tY-GtuWj6NGIlJVwg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)?

Comment: Thanks for looking at the question. The post was set on hold and I narrowed my post down to one question. Does it improve the post or can you clarify how to make the post better?